# How to type non-ASCII character (ö) to `sudo` when keyboard layout doesn't fit?

Tags: linux, command-line, passwords, sudo

Unfortunately I have broken my system during upgrading Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04.

I can access the command line using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, but to use `sudo` I need to type in umlauts, since they are in my password. But the shell keyboard has reverted to the English layout.

I have tried to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>246</kbd> but it does not work.

Does anyone have another idea how I can type in umlauts? or revert to the German layout without using `sudo`?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo -S` will read the password from the stdin. Now you need a way to print your password to stdout so you can pipe it to `sudo -S`.

In Bash in my Debian 9 with UTF-8 support each of the following commands prints `pa%wörd` with a trailing newline character:

- `echo -e 'pa%w\xc3\xb6rd'` – because of how `echo` builtin expands its arguments with `-e`;
- `/bin/echo -e 'pa%w\xc3\xb6rd'` – because of how `echo` command expands its arguments with `-e`.
- `printf '%s\n' $'pa%w\xc3\xb6rd'` – because of how Bash expands `$'…'`;
- `printf 'pa%%w\303\266rd\n'` – because of how format of `printf` works;
- `printf '%b\n' 'pa%w\0303\0266rd'` – because of how `%b` in `printf` works.

In general there's more of them. Note `echo` is [not the best choice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618) and `$'…'` requires your shell to understand it. The last two solutions with `printf` are portable.

Hexadecimal encoding `\xc3\xb6` was taken from the output of `printf '%s' 'ö' | xxd` on a system where I can type or paste `ö`. The information is also available [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96#Encoding). `\303\266` is from the output of `printf '%s' 'ö' | od -d`; alternatively one can convert the hexadecimal values to octal.

If you can print your password to stdout then you can gain sudo access:

```
printf 'pa%%w\303\266rd\n' | sudo -S whoami
```

Starting an interactive shell like this may be tricky because such shell needs its stdin to be a terminal, not a pipe. Hopefully your `sudo` caches credentials, so if you invoke the above command first and `sudo su -` just after, then the latter will probably work.

If not, write a script that prints your password and use it with `sudo -A`:

```
SUDO_ASKPASS='/path/to/script' sudo -A su -
```